# Screen Shift to Left using Flutter Reaction Button Pub

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I'm gonna use flutter reaction button plugin on new my app.
But when I put the reaction button, and push the icon, Preview icon box is shown to right side and main view is moved to left site.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go7mu.png)

Here is the Item Codes to show pics and reaction button.

```
class CommunicationItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const CommunicationItem({@required this.communication});
  final Communication communication;

  @override
  _CommunicationItemState createState() => _CommunicationItemState();
}

class _CommunicationItemState extends State<CommunicationItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
      elevation: 2,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/showImage.png'),
            spaceH8,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  FlutterReactionButtonCheck(
                    onReactionChanged: (reaction, index, isChecked) {
                      print('reaction selected index test: $index');
                    },
                    reactions: data.reactions,
                    initialReaction: data.defaultInitialReaction,
                    selectedReaction: data.reactions[0],
                  ),
```

I know the other solution like this link.
https://githubmemory.com/repo/GeekAbdelouahed/flutter-reaction-button/issues/22

But I don't know the solution by codes.
Please help it.

V/r,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the transition of the CupertinoPageRoute, try to set the page transition to none.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved in version `3.0.0` and above